# sum all values in the mongodb according to input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

with the help of a tutorial on youtube i could finaly get the entry from an input, get the documents from mongoatlas as per this input and show it on the page.

my project is like this: the shop owner will input the name of the client, cpf (like a social security #) and how much he owes.

this part is ok. and in the serch page, the shop ower can query by cpf or name and it would show the customer and his total debt.
but I'd like to show how much outstanding debt the shop has.

so i came up with a "total" key. in each entry, i will have a default value for total

which means, the user can type the name of the client and it will bring the client and his debt, but if the user type "total" it would show the total outstanding debt of his store.

but i couldnt figure out how to sum all the debt fiels.

```js
            const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');
            fetch('getUsers',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({payload: e.value})
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                let payload = data.payload;
                searchResults.innerHTML = '';
                if (payload.length < 1){
                    searchResults.innerHTML = '<p>Nome não encontrado</p>';
                    return;
                }
                payload.forEach((item,index)=>{
                    if (index <0) searchResults.innerHTML += '<hr>';
                    searchResults.innerHTML += `<p>${item.firstName} ${item.lastName} .. Total de dívidas R$ ${item.dividaUm+item.dividaDois}.</p>`;
                });
                    return;
            });
```

i have an input with onkeyup="sendData(this) to call the above function

and it will fetch the following:

```js
app.post('/getUsers', async (req, res) =>{
    let payload = req.body.payload.trim();
    let search = await User.find({firstName: {$regex: new RegExp('^'+payload+'.*','i')}}).exec();
    //console.log(payload)

    //limitar resultados a 10
    search = search.slice(0,10);
    res.send({payload: search});
});
```

user.find(firstName:)

but i cant figure out a way to agregate all debts if he types total

inside my function i created an if statement

```js
        function sendData(e){
        if (e.value !== "total") {
            const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');
            fetch('getUsers',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({payload: e.value})
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                let payload = data.payload;
                searchResults.innerHTML = '';
                if (payload.length < 1){
                    searchResults.innerHTML = '<p>Nome não encontrado</p>';
                    return;
                }
                payload.forEach((item,index)=>{
                    if (index <0) searchResults.innerHTML += '<hr>';
                    searchResults.innerHTML += `<p>${item.firstName} ${item.lastName} .. Total de dívidas R$ ${item.dividaUm+item.dividaDois}.</p>`;
                });
                    return;
            });
        } else {
            const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');
            fetch('getTotalDivida',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({payload: e.value})
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                let payload = data.payload;
                searchResults.innerHTML = '';
                if (payload.length < 1){
                    searchResults.innerHTML = '<p>Nome não encontrado</p>';
                    return;
                }
                payload.forEach((item,index)=>{
                    if (index <0) searchResults.innerHTML += '<hr>';
                    searchResults.innerHTML += `<p>Total de dívidas R$ ${item.dividaUm+item.dividaDois}.</p>`;
                });
                    return;
            });
        }
    }
```

but it turns out, when i type "total" it will give me the total for each customer.

pls help.

Answer (score 0):

since i copied and pasted this solution from a youtube channel i wanst able to figure out why he named the variable payload and what it was doing there

but then i got thinking, if he's using a forEach i can assume i may come as an array.

so i thought if it's an array then i will treat it as if i had named a variabled payload and assinged an array to it.

then i tried for loops but reduce got the job.

the solution i was looking for is:

```js
const total = payload.reduce((acc, obj) =>{
return acc + obj.dividaUm + obj.dividaDois
},0);
searchResults.innerHTML += `<p>Total de dívidas R$ ${total}.</p>`
```